# How to have vertical record and header in HTML table using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the HTML structure like this:

```
<table border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>header1</td><td>header2</td><td>header3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11</td><td>22</td><td>33</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

How could I use CSS so that this table have vertical row layout like this (vertical record and header):
http://pastebay.net/1181219

Btw is it possible to re-define the HTML structure so that the problem could be easy to be solved? I hope I can solve using CSS instead of JavaScript.

Comment: Write your HTML so that it displays that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th> Header 1

        <td> L1 C2
        <td> L1 C3
        <td> L1 C4

    <tr>
        <th> Header 2

        <td> L2 C2
        <td> L2 C3
        <td> L2 C4

    <tr>
        <th> Header 3

        <td> L3 C2
        <td> L3 C3
        <td> L3 C4
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#mytable tr > th{
    background:#69B;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With JavaScript, you can pivot rows into columns by looping over the cells.  On the first row, you can determine the number of rows needed based on the number of cells in the first row.  This assumes all rows have an equal number of cells.

```
var $table = $("<table>");
$("tr").each(function (row) {
    $(this).find("td").each(function (idx) {
        if (row === 0) {
            $table.append($("<tr>").append(this));
        }
        else {
            $table.find('tr').eq(idx).append(this);
        }
    });
});
$table.appendTo("body");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/tkqRa/